# How to increase video framerate while simultaneously decreasing the video duration?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a video file that has an fps of 30, but video players (e.g., VLC) read the fps as 25 (I don't know why!). This causes a mismatch between the actual video duration and what the video players show. For example, the time difference between the video timestamps shown at the top-center of the start and the end frames (see attached images) is 12 minutes and 36 seconds, but the video duration shown by the video player is 15 minutes and 7 seconds (see bottom right corner in either of the two images). I think the video players are multiplying the original video duration by 1.2 (30/25).

I tried using `ffmpeg` to change the fps to 30 using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fps=30 output.mp4
```

But the `ffmpeg` [doc on changing frame rate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) says that the "**the output duration of the video will stay the same.**"

What changes do I need to make in my code so that the video duration shown in the player matches the actual video duration?

Start frame:

[image]

End frame:

[image]

Comment: So when you playback the video, it's too slow?

Comment: @kesh, not too slow, but the time doesn't match! So, 10 minutes of video player correspond to ~8.33 minutes of the actual video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is an incorrect framerate (25 fps) is stored in the file (vlc reports what the file tells it), you can try:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i input.mp4 [-c copy] output.mp4
```

- Specifying `-r 30` *input* option overrides the framerate specified by the file.
- Try with `-c copy` first (no bracket) to see if you can copy the encoded data. If it doesn't work, remove it and re-encode the video stream.

Comment: Great! The solution without `[-c copy]` worked for me. The video times now perfectly align with each other. Thanks!